# Using expect to compare values from .then(), returns undefined

Tags: cypress

I have a function that is named **DateManagement.js**:

```
checkSalesDate: () => {
    let itemTagObj = {}

    cy.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Updated')]")
        .then(date => {
            itemTagObj.initialDate = date[0].innerHTML

            itemTagObj.manualDate = 'Updated: 08 Aug 2022 06:54:50'
        })

    return itemTagObj
}
```

I am trying to compare the values inside `initialDate` and `manualDate` Here is my main script

```
import { DateManagement } from '../functions/index'

describe('test date', () => {
    it('test date', function() {
        itemTagObj = DateManagement.checkUpdatedSalesTag()

        expect(itemTagObj.initialDate).to.not.equal(itemTagObj.manualDate)
    })
})
```

When I run this script, My result is *undefined* for both the values being compared
[image]

If I try to `cy.log` the **itemTagObj**, it shows that it successfully fetched the values from `checkSalesDate` function

[image]

Is there something missing here that I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can return a chain with the `itemTagObj` as a subject from your function

```js
checkSalesDate: () => {
    let itemTagObj = {}

    return cy.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Updated')]")
        .then(date => {
            itemTagObj.initialDate = date[0].innerHTML

            itemTagObj.manualDate = 'Updated: 08 Aug 2022 06:54:50'
            return itemTagObj 
        })
}
```

And use it as follows:

```js
import {DateManagement} from '../functions/index'

describe('test date', () => {
  it('test date', function () {
    DateManagement.checkUpdatedSalesTag().then(itemTagObj => {
      expect(itemTagObj.initialDate).to.not.equal(itemTagObj.manualDate)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
import {DateManagement} from '../functions/index'

describe('test date', () => {
  it('test date', function () {
    itemTagObj = DateManagement.checkUpdatedSalesTag()
    cy.then(() => {
      expect(itemTagObj.initialDate).to.not.equal(itemTagObj.manualDate)
    })
  })
})
```